# IIS switch paths using a script

Tags: iis, powershell, web-deployment

Not quite sure how to achieve this, or if it's at all possible? I currently have two websites defined in IIS.

- MySite_Production
- MySite_Staging

These sites work out of two physical folders on the C drive.

- MySite_SlotA
- MySite_SlotB

I am using Web Deploy from Visual Studio 2012 to push any new deployments to `MySite_Staging`, which let's say is running out of `MySite_SlotA`. When I've carried out some cursory checks I stop `MySite_Staging` then I go into `MySite_Production` and change the path to `MySite_SlotA`. This is about as seamless as I can make the deployment process on a single web-server.

My question is, can I write some kind of Powershell script or bat file that will switch the paths for me? I'm not great with Powershell but happy to look into this if it has the potential to automate this routine.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. Maybe its better to think of a script that move the staging files to production folder rather than IIS pointing to staging folder once you are happy. What happens to production folder after you change path. How do you do backup or cleanup of production.

Comment: Moving the staging files to the production folder will corrupt the running instance and throw errors for those using the site, until the script has moved all the files. When I change the path from slotA to slotB I leave slotA untouched so I can rollback if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Switching would cause similar issues to existing users but thats a different debate.

Comment: Yeh but way less, as the files are there it just needs to recompile.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit of necromancy reviving this, but I just had a similar need for some powershell to change the physical path of a web app in iis.
There's a nice one-liner you can use (technically 2 since you need to import a library).

```
Import WebAdministration
Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' -Name PhysicalPath -Value C:\Deploy\MyAwesomeWebsitePhysicalPath
```

Obviously, you'd need to change `Default Web Site` and `C:\Deploy\MyAwesomeWebsitePhysicalPath` to whatever suits your situation.

Comment: Awesome, now I can easily automate IIS path switching, so I don't need to get up at 1AM to flip the switch.  There were actually a bunch of posts that didn't work or were overly complicated.  This one *simply* did the trick!